# Gif Works on emulator but not on device

Tags: android, android-emulator, gif

I am using a custom GIFView class to display an animated gif in android in a full screen layout. The gif is displayed and animated on my AVDs running Android API 8 and 16, but not on my device running  Android 4.0.4. On my device it is as though the GIFView is not added to the layout. It is a blank screen save for the title bar. I have included the relevant code.

```
    setContentView(R.layout.fullscreen);
    LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.fullscreenlayout);
    layout.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
    if (imageType.equals("image/gif")){
        GIFView view = new GIFView(this);
        layout.addView(view);
        view.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
        view.setMovie(loadGifFromWeb(imageUrl, imageSize));
        view.setOnClickListener(imageListener);
    }
    else{

        ImageView imageView = new ImageView(this);
        layout.addView(imageView);
        imageView.setImageDrawable(loadImageFromWeb(imageUrl));
        imageView.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
        imageView.setOnClickListener(imageListener);
    }
```

the logcat is as follows

```
     11-19 23:45:09.934: I/dalvikvm(7087): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
     11-19 23:45:10.445: I/dalvikvm(7087): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
     11-19 23:45:10.465: I/dalvikvm(7087): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
     11-19 23:45:10.955: I/dalvikvm(7087): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
     11-19 23:45:10.955: I/dalvikvm(7087): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
     11-19 23:45:11.276: I/Adreno200-EGLSUB(7087): <ConfigWindowMatch:2078>: Format RGBA_8888.
     11-19 23:45:11.286: D/OpenGLRenderer(7087): Flushing caches (mode 0)
```

I used the GIFView class from [here](http://droid-blog.net/2011/10/14/tutorial-how-to-use-animated-gifs-in-android-part-1/)

Thanks for your help.

EDIT* Upon further investigation, I found that i have the same problem with the base tutorial code. The gif plays fine on my emulator, but not on my device. (T989)

Comment: loadImageFromWeb..? do u have internet in your device????

Comment: yes have you set the permissions for internet access on your app?

Comment: yes i have internet permissions

Comment: Couldn't you just use `myActivity.this.AddContentView(View v)`

Answer (score 0):

You haven't required any internet permission for showing GIF images. Please refer this

https://stackoverflow.com/a/25967271/2732632