# GIF image works on emulator but not in real device?

Tags: android, android-animation, animated-gif

i am trying to display gif image i have used this code

**MainActivity**

```
       public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(new MYGIFView(this));
       }

 }
```

and the **MYGIFView** class:

```
 public class MYGIFView extends View {

Movie movie,movie1;
InputStream is=null,is1=null;
long moviestart;
public MYGIFView(Context context) {
super(context);
is=context.getResources().openRawResource(R.drawable.piggy);
movie=Movie.decodeStream(is);

}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);
super.onDraw(canvas);
long now=android.os.SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
System.out.println("now="+now);
if (moviestart == 0) { // first time
moviestart = now;

}
System.out.println("\tmoviestart="+moviestart);
int relTime = (int)((now - moviestart) % movie.duration()) ;
System.out.println("time="+relTime+"\treltime="+movie.duration());
movie.setTime(relTime);
movie.draw(canvas,this.getWidth()/2-20,this.getHeight()/2-40);
this.invalidate();
}
}
```

It shows gif image from drawale folder in emulator and gif worrks but when i run this in **real device it shows nothing**... Whats the problem here??

Answer (score 4):

Movie Object is not work properly on Device above(4.x) as hardware acceleration is enabled in these devices. So by making hardware acceleration disabled, you can make images work on both emulator and on real device.

1. You can disabled hardware acceleration by adding

   android:hardwareAccelerated="false"

in your manifest file inder activity tag

```
<activity
    android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:hardwareAccelerated="false"
    android:label="@string/app_name" > 
</activity>
```

2.you can also disabled hardware acceration programatically

for example: MYGIFView is your custom view where you are going to show your GIF images

```
MYGIFView mMYGIFView =(MYGIFView)findViewById(R.id.myGifImageView);
mMYGIFView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
```

By using this your GIF image will show on both emulator and real device :)